# Angular realtime changes

Tags: angular-cli, angular2-components

Angular components generated form angular-cli don't render on mobile devices within localhost during the development process to test it on mobile devices and I think it's related to the relative/absolute path for the components on the final dist files and I think it detects it as Not found resources

I need to find a way to be able to display these components through localhost on mobile?

Thank you

Comment: mention what you did and what error you are facing in. Put the error being printed in console. How you are running on mobile. did you deployed on any server?

Comment: I'm using "ng serve" and the component runs well on the desktop browser but it gives a blank page on mobile but when I type any html tags in the index.html (root) it appears on both with no problems

Comment: How are you accessing it on mobile page?

Comment: At first, I'm using this command through cmd
`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`

then I'm trying to access the project from the same connection on mobile

**192.168.1.4:4200**

Comment: You can use Chrome Remote Device Debugging to know more about error and add the same in your question. Please follow link
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/